# Remove Static IP & DNS on all Interfaces - Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, reset

I need a Window's batch script that will remove the static IP address (Change to DHCP), Remove the set DNS, and enable all the network interfaces *without having to specify the interface name*; since some interfaces may be named differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created this last night, and everything seems to work the way it should.

```
@echo off

: Disable Static IP/Enable DHCP    Remove DNS     Enable NICs
for /f "skip=2 tokens=3*" %%i in ('netsh interface show interface') do (
netsh int ip set address "%%j" dhcp >nul 2>&1
netsh int ip set dns "%%j" dhcp >nul 2>&1
netsh interface set interface name="%%j" admin=enabled >nul 2>&1
)
```

If you want to take it a step further and clear the DNS Cache, add this to the next line.

```
ipconfig /flushdns >nul 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a batch file with this script which will change your IP from static to DHCP.

```
@echo off
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Wi-Fi" source=dhcp   
@echo off 
netsh interface ipv4 set dns name="Wi-Fi" source=dhcp
```

Comment: Read the question - 'without having to specify the interface name'. Question was already correctly answered.